# How to change the scene after gaze Timer done?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Now I am doing a project for my final term in university and my area changed the scene by gazing(google VR SDK).

At first, I just put a code to change the scene. It worked. But I want some enhance, so I used gaze timer which I watched at youtube (link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bmMaVTV8UqY)

Now, the gaze Timer animation is working but the SceneSwitcher function in NexScene1 code isn't working.

I've done 'build' after adding the new scene that I add gaze timer function.
Also, I used tagged which shown in the youtube.

That's all I did.

```
public class VRGaze : MonoBehaviour {

    public Image imgGaze;

    public float totalTime = 2;
    bool gvrStatus;
    float gvrTimer;

    public int distanceOfRay = 10;
    private RaycastHit _hit;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (gvrStatus)
        {
            gvrTimer += Time.deltaTime;
            imgGaze.fillAmount = gvrTimer / totalTime;
        }
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ViewportPointToRay(new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f));

        if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out _hit, distanceOfRay))
        {
            if(imgGaze.fillAmount == 1 && _hit.transform.CompareTag("NexScene1"))
            {
                _hit.transform.gameObject.GetComponent<NexScene1>().SceneSwitcher();
            }

        }
    }

    public void GVROn()    {
        gvrStatus = true;
    }

    public void GVROff()    {
        gvrStatus = false;
        gvrTimer = 0;
        imgGaze.fillAmount = 0;
    }

}


public class NexScene1 : MonoBehaviour {
    public UnityEngine.UI.Scrollbar obj_scroll_;

    public GameObject player;

    public void PointEnter()
    {
        StartCoroutine(TimeToAction());
    }

    public void PointExit()
    {
        StopAllCoroutines();
    }

    public void SceneSwitcher()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Page2");
    }
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

Not an actual error but just the SwitchScene function is not called at VRGaze

Not an error but the console says:

> It is recommended to use GvrPointerPhysicsRaycaster or
>   GvrPointerGrahpicRaycaster with GvrPointerInputModule.

Comment: did you try breakpoints and debug what actually `isn't working`? Are all conditions fulfilled?

Comment: Put in some debug messages to see what values you have